# Parse XML response only if certain tags are available

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

There are two types of items returned:

```
<LineStatus ID="0" StatusDetails="">
    <BranchDisruptions/>
    <Line ID="1" Name="Bakerloo"/>
    <Status ID="GS" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Good Service" IsActive="true">   
       <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
    </Status>
 </LineStatus>
```

or

```
<LineStatus ID="5" StatusDetails="Severe delays">
    <BranchDisruptions>
        <BranchDisruption>
           <StationTo ID="106" Name="High Barnet"/>
           <StationFrom ID="35" Name="Camden Town"/>
           <Status ID="SD" CssClass="DisruptedService" Description="Severe Delays" IsActive="true">
           <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
           </Status>
        </BranchDisruption>
    </BranchDisruptions>
     <Line ID="5" Name="Northern"/>
       <Status ID="SD" CssClass="DisruptedService" Description="Severe Delays" IsActive="true">
         <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
      </Status>
</LineStatus>
```

As you can see, the second element also has BranchDisruptions details filled in.
I need to build three `ArrayList<String>` after parsing the XML response, one containing all the `LineStatus StatusDetails`, one containing `Line Name` and one list containing all the `Line Status Description`.

My problem is that I want to ignore the Status from `<BranchDisruption>` since I don't need it. So far I have managed to get the list with all the names, but the list with statuses contains Branch statuses also.

```
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineStatus");
for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.getLength(); i++)
      {
     Node node = nodelist.item(i);
     Element Te = (Element) node;
     listStatusDetails.add(Te.getAttribute("StatusDetails"));

        NodeList ttLine = Te.getElementsByTagName("Line");
        for (int j = 0; j < ttLine.getLength(); j++)
        {
           Node nNode = ttLine.item(j);
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           listLineNames.add(eElement.getAttribute("Name"));
        }
     }

        NodeList ttStatus = Te.getElementsByTagName("Status");
        for (int j = 0; j < ttStatus.getLength(); j++)
        {
           Node nNode = ttStatus.item(j);
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           listLineStatuses.add(eElement.getAttribute("Description"));
        }
     }
  }
```

So as you can see in the code above, the Status is taken both from Lines and from BranchDisruption.

I want to ignore the  on my parsing, so only the Status from Line is parsed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I know that saying "I wouldn't do it like that" isn't particularly useful, but it might be worth looking at jdom ( www.jdom.org ). It makes this sort of XML processing much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your code and alter it like this:

```
    NodeList ttStatus = Te.getElementsByTagName("Status");
    for (int j = 0; j < ttStatus.getLength(); j++)
    {
       Node nNode = ttStatus.item(j);
       if (nNode.getParentNode().getNodeName().equals("LineStatus")) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           listLineStatuses.add(eElement.getAttribute("Description"));
       }
    }
```

However the XML you are receiving isn't very nice to work with. An id should always be unique in an XML document and should not be used as a flag for the result. If you can manipulate your provider to change their XML please do.

If you succeed with that you should be able to use getElementById instead which would be both faster and more accurate. The current XML doesn't make this an option though.

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to use xmlparser to parsing xml reponce.its too much easier way rather than this.

This is best demo example for xmlParsing:

[reference link](http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94)

I hope its useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

XPath can be used for get only required statuses:

```
    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nl=(NodeList)path.evaluate("LineStatus/Status/@Description", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```